# Dynamically populated controls do not trigger events - jQuery 3.6.0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a dashboard with a start and stop feature but apparently the dynamically populated controls are not triggering the event. The code for the dynamic controls are

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/getChannelData",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      var rowHtml = "";
      $.each(response, function (key, value) {
        rowHtml =
          " <div class='col-xl-6 col-lg-12'>" +
          " <div class='card card-chart'>" +
          "<div class='card-header card-header-success'>" +
          "<div >Status : <a>" +
          value.State +
          "</a></div>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='card-body'>" +
          "<h4 class='card-title'>" +
          value.Name +
          "</h4>" +
          "<h4 class='card-title'><a class='channelid'>" +
          value.ChannelId +
          "</a></h4><p class='card-category'><div class='btn-group'><input class='btn mb-2 mb-md-0 btn-quarternary btn-block btn-round' type='button' value='Start' id='start1'><input class='btn mb-2 mb-md-0 btn-quarternary btn-block btn-round' type='button' value='Stop' id='stop1'></input></div></div></div> </div>";
      });
      $(".row").append(rowHtml);
    }
  });
});
```

The controls are populating ok but the event trigger on it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var channelID = $(".channelid").val();
  $("#start1").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/channelTest-startstop?state=Start&channelid=2107494",
      type: "POST",
      headers: { "x-api-key": "PUoZWYihWE8DZbC58sng8zOZLQcG93s5mNTedxea" },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#stop1").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/channelTest-startstop?state=Stop&channelid=" +
        channelID,
      type: "POST",
      headers: { "x-api-key": "PUoZWYihWE8DZbC58sng8zOZLQcG93s5mNTedxea" },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated at this point..

Comment: You are having duplicate ids  so change them to *class* . Also ,as elements are dynamically generated you can change your event handler like this : `$(".row").on("click",".start1",function () { //all codes here })`  same for other input as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlfow. You are assigning `click` callbacks before the elements exist. As was suggested, use `.on()` to assign the callback or assign it as the element is created.

Comment: @Swati - did not work, still same problem, it seems dynamically populating controls do not trigger AJAX calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {

  function sendStart(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/channelTest-startstop?state=Start&channelid=" + $(event.target).data("channel-id"),
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": "PUoZWYihWE8DZbC58sng8zOZLQcG93s5mNTedxea"
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function sendStop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/channelTest-startstop?state=Stop&channelid=" + $(event.target).data("channel-id"),
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": "PUoZWYihWE8DZbC58sng8zOZLQcG93s5mNTedxea"
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  }

  function makeCard(data) {
    var col = $("<div>", {
      class: "col-xl-6 col-lg-12"
    });
    var card = $("<div>", {
      class: "card card-chart"
    }).appendTo(col);
    var head = $("<div>", {
      class: "card-header card-header-success"
    }).appendTo(card);
    $("<div>").html("Status: <a>" + data.Status + "</a>").appendTo(head);
    var body = $("<div>", {
      class: "card-body"
    }).appendTo(card);
    var title = $("<h4>", {
      class: "card-title"
    }).html(data.Name).appendTo(body);
    var titleId = $("<h4>", {
      class: "card-title"
    }).html(data.ChannelId).appendTo(body);
    $("<p>", {
      class: "card-category"
    }).appendTo(body);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "btn-group"
    }).appendTo($("p", body));
    var start = $("<input>", {
      class: "btn mb-2 mb-md-0 btn-quarternary btn-block btn-round",
      type: "button",
      value: "Start",
      "data-channel-id": data.ChannelId,
      id: "start-" + $(".btn-group input[id^='start-']").length + 1
    }).appendTo($("p > div", body));
    var stop = $("<input>", {
      class: "btn mb-2 mb-md-0 btn-quarternary btn-block btn-round",
      type: "button",
      value: "Stop",
      "data-channel-id": data.ChannelId,
      id: "stop-" + $(".btn-group input[id^='stop-']").length + 1
    }).appendTo($("p > div", body));

    start.click(sendStart);
    stop.click(sendStop);

    return col;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://ul2qo9rru1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/getChannelData",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function(key, value) {
        $(".row").append(makeCard(value));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Break down all the steps into their own functions to help assigning event callbacks. This will iterate the response, all the rows, and bind the `click` event callbacks. Passing the Channel ID to the Data attribute to each of the buttons allows you to grab it form the `event` object.